# How to automatically run method when the ASP page is loaded?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a page which displays the following content when it is loaded:

```
<div>
  <img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /> Generating PDF Document, please wait.
<div>
```

At the same time, I want to run this method the code behind automatically:

```
private void GeneratePdf()
{
    ...
}
```

Lastly, I want to redirect the user to the `File.pdf` path once the `GeneratePdf()` method is completed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Page_Load` event as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_events.asp). Additionally, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a great explanation of the page life cycle. You should take a look at it. Here is some sample code from the above link:

```
<script runat="server">//This script runs on the server and dishes up some output for the page.
Sub Page_Load
lbl1.Text="The date and time is " & now()
End Sub
</script>

<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<h3><asp:label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></h3>//This generates the textbox that will be given a value from the above script.
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, could you explain to me what goes to the page and what goes to the code behind in your example please?

Comment: @Boris It is not MY code, its theirs actually as I noted. But whats going on in the code behind is the `now()` function and it assigns its return value to `labl1.Text` which is included in the page code you would say, under <h3>. See my edit. Alse have a look at the links, mainly the second one, which does it more of a conventional server-side way

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use GeneratePDF with ajax, so you can use like

```
$.ajax({
url: '/pdf/fiele_to_generate_pdf.aspx',
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: $.toJSON(jsonObj),
processData: false,
dataType: 'html',    
async: false,
success: function(html) {
    window.location.href = '/pdf/example.pdf';      
}});
```

so for loading you can use jquery, there is a good [plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) named BlockUI you can use it before your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asp:Timer control to indicate when your code-behind should be called

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timer1" Interval="3000" OnTick="timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
```

Then implement the Timer's Tick event. This will be called after 3 seconds (3000ms) as specified in the markup

```
protected void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GeneratePdf();
    Response.Redirect("~/somepath/generatedPDF.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented something similar myself. However, using that approach I never get to see the content of the `div` mentioned in the question. The page is just plain white, waiting for the `GeneratePdf()` to finish and then it redirects to the PDF file. What I am trying to achieve is to have that gif loop and a message shown to the user while they wait for the method to finish and redirect. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @Boris You can use the `asp:Timer` control. Mind you, you also need an `asp:ScriptManager` on your page. Good Luck.